# Estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar los datos traidos de la base de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Me pidieron que en el Index de mi pagina web tenga un filtro por fechas, entonces use dos calendarios y ambas fechas las mando al controlador. Mi problema es que se me redirige a la vista de error pero no me esta trayendo ningun mensaje, y esto usando `ViewData["ERROR"] o Viewbag o throw new Exception` y nada, a veces me tira error por problemas de pool pero eso pasa con otras consultas, para ésta no estaría funcionando. Las consultas si las pruebo directamente en MySql funcionan perfectamente

Éste es mi html con los dos calendarios

```html
            <form action="~/Home/ConsultarPorFecha" method="post" id="form" class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="desdeFecha">Desde: </label>
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" id="desdeFecha" name="desdeFecha" required type="date" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="hastaFecha">Hasta: </label>
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" id="hastaFecha" name="hastaFecha" required type="date" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 align-center">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" value="BUSCAR" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Éste es el [HttpPost] del controlador:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ConsultarPorFecha(string desdeFecha, string hastaFecha)
    {
        string consulta;
        List<EntregasViewModel> entregasViewModels;
        string[] fecha1, fecha2;
        try
        {
            fecha1 = desdeFecha.Split("/");
            fecha2 = hastaFecha.Split("/");

            consulta = "select DISTINCT e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha from Entrega e INNER JOIN Pedido p where fecha between '" + fecha1[2] + "-" + fecha1[1] + "-" + fecha1[0]+ " 00-00-00' and '" + fecha2[2] + "-" + fecha2[1] + "-" + fecha2[0] + " 24-00-00' GROUP BY e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha";

            entregasViewModels = SelectPorFecha(consulta);

            return View("FiltrarFecha", entregasViewModels);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData["ERROR"] = ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ésta es la última consulta que intenté porque pensaba que estaba ahi el error (no descarto que no esté alli), pero tambien probé otras como en vez de hacer split simplemente usaba las variables "desdeFecha" y "hastaFecha".

```
private List<EntregasViewModel> SelectPorFecha(string consulta)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection;
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            List<EntregasViewModel> entregasViewModels;
            string[] fecha;
            string respuestaBD;
            try
            {
                entregasViewModels = new List<EntregasViewModel>();
                connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";" + ";username=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";");

                cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, connection);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 12000000;
                connection.Open();

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EntregasViewModel entrega = new EntregasViewModel();
                    entrega.NumeroEntrega = reader["Entrega"].ToString();
                    entrega.NumeroPedido = reader["Pedido"].ToString();
                    entrega.NumeroRemito = reader["Remito"].ToString();
                    fecha = reader["Fecha"].ToString().Split(" ");
                    entrega.Fecha = fecha[0].ToString();
                    entrega.Hora = fecha[1].ToString();

                    //consulta = "SELECT COUNT(Entrega) AS 'cantidad' FROM Entrega WHERE Entrega = '" + reader["Entrega"].ToString() + "'";
                    //entrega.CantFotos = consultarCantImgsBD(consulta).ToString();

                    entregasViewModels.Add(entrega);
                }

                connection.Close();
                connection.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
                return entregasViewModels;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["ERROR"] = ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Y ésta es la conexion en MySql que quiero que me retorne una lista:

```
private List<EntregasViewModel> SelectPorFecha(string consulta)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        List<EntregasViewModel> entregasViewModels;
        string[] fecha;
        string respuestaBD;
        try
        {
            entregasViewModels = new List<EntregasViewModel>();
            connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";" + ";username=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";");

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, connection);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 12000000;
            connection.Open();

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                EntregasViewModel entrega = new EntregasViewModel();
                entrega.NumeroEntrega = reader["Entrega"].ToString();
                entrega.NumeroPedido = reader["Pedido"].ToString();
                entrega.NumeroRemito = reader["Remito"].ToString();
                fecha = reader["Fecha"].ToString().Split(" ");
                entrega.Fecha = fecha[0].ToString();
                entrega.Hora = fecha[1].ToString();

                //consulta = "SELECT COUNT(Entrega) AS 'cantidad' FROM Entrega WHERE Entrega = '" + reader["Entrega"].ToString() + "'";
                //entrega.CantFotos = consultarCantImgsBD(consulta).ToString();

                entregasViewModels.Add(entrega);
            }

            connection.Close();
            connection.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
            return entregasViewModels;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData["ERROR"] = ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Como veran, dentro del reader intente de hacer otra consuklta ya que cada entrega tiene una n cantidad de fotos para cada una, y la consulta lo que haria es traerme la cantidad de fotos de la entrega que está pasando actualmente. Pensé que podría llegar a ser eso pero no lo es ya que lo probé luego de comentarlo y no funcionó.

No puedo debuggear ya que estoy utilizando autenticacion por microsoft y no me deja conectarme via localhost.

Esta es la vista que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio hay otras consultas que sí me lo muestra pero que fueron arregladas ( o parecen que fueron arregladas al menos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no usa Entity Framework ?? Y porque no desactiva la autenticación para que pueda hacer debug ???. Echele un vistazo a esta página donde vienen varios métodos para enviar formularios: https://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/10/14/c%c3%b3mo-recibir-datos-desde-un-formulario-post-en-aspnet-mvc?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1, me parece que el tipo date que genera el input no es de tipo string o al menos eso creo, no se si deben ser parámetros datetime o bien pruebe usando dynamic en lugar de string en el controlador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los errores más comunes cuando accedes a base de datos suelen estar en la lectura de valores `DBNull`, si una columna en base de datos permite valores nulos deberías asegurarte de comprobar estos antes de utilizarlos.

Ejemplo:

```
entrega.NumeroEntrega = reader["Entrega"] != DBNull.Value ? 
    reader["Entrega"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

También deberías utilizar los bloques `using` para realizar las conexiones a base de datos y así te aseguras de cerrar cada conexión. Esto evitaría la captura del segunda error que muestras.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr)) 
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
   {
       conn.Open();

       using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while(reader.Read())
           {
              // TODO...
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Y con el tema de la consulta dentro del reader, cuál sería la manera o camino mas optimo?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el formato de esos input tipo fecha al llegar al controlador no es "2022/09/24" sino "2022-09-24" por lo que al querer separar en array la fecha de tipo string deberías utilizar mejor:

```
        fecha1 = desdeFecha.Split('-');
        fecha2 = hastaFecha.Split('-');
```

Espero que ese sea el error ya que de la forma que lo estas haciendo en "fecha1" y "fecha2" se esta guardando un array tipo string de longitud 0, por lo que al tratar de concatenar "fecha1[2] + fecha1[1]" estos dan error porque no existen.